# Useage of scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
def fun(x):
    return x**3 + x**2

derivative(fun,1)
```

The answer comes out to be 6 but it should be 5. Am I doing something wrong?

In the official [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) it says to use dx=1e-6 . Why should I use this here ? And what is the use of dx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code (`[source]` on the doc page), and a bit of experimentation, I found that:

```
In [472]: derivative(fun,1)
Out[472]: 6.0
In [473]: derivative(fun,1,1)
Out[473]: 6.0
In [474]: dx=1;(fun(1+dx)-fun(1-dx))/(2*dx)
Out[474]: 6.0
In [475]: derivative(fun,1,.5)
Out[475]: 5.25
In [476]: dx=.5;(fun(1+dx)-fun(1-dx))/(2*dx)
Out[476]: 5.25
In [477]: derivative(fun,1,.1)
Out[477]: 5.010000000000001
In [478]: dx=.1;(fun(1+dx)-fun(1-dx))/(2*dx)
Out[478]: 5.010000000000001
```

With the default `n` and `order` it estimates the derivative from 2 points, one on each side of the `x0`.  The smaller the `dx` the better you will capture the slope at a `x0`, with the caution about rounding errors if it's too small.